# rxjs expand operator with switchMap

Tags: axios, rxjs, nestjs

I have a list of students, for each student, I have to access the address. I will get the student list in pagination. so I used the 'expand' operator to get all students. but I am not able to get the address for each student.
**Student List**

```
{
  students: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'ABC'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'XYZ'
    }
  ],
 nextPageToken: 'Aqw12'
}
```

Now using the student's id I have to fetch the address.
Here is my sample code to get the student's list with the rxjs expand operator.

```
const connection = this.searchStudent(nextPageToken).pipe(
    expand((students: StudentsDto) => {
        if (students.nextPageToken){
            nextPageToken = students.nextPageToken;
            return this.searchStudent(nextPageToken);
        }else{
            return new Observable as Observable<StudentsDto>;
        }
    })
);

const subscription = connection.subscribe({
    next(response: StudentsDto) {
        response.students.forEach(async (student: StudentDto) => {
            console.log(student);
        });
    },
    error(e) {
        console.log(e)
    },
    complete() {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    },
});
```

Now I am not able to get, what operator should I apply to get the address.
for address, I have implemented API in **this.getAddress(studentId)** function which return Observables.

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: Assuming your connection observable is working fine, then you can use a mergeMap which takes in array of StudentDto and get individual addresses out of it

Comment: @Pankaj Yes connection observable is working fine. Should I use mergeMap inside the expand operator? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
const connection = this.searchStudent(nextPageToken).pipe(
    expand((response: StudentsDto) => {
        if (response.nextPageToken){
            nextPageToken = response.nextPageToken;
            return this.searchStudent(nextPageToken);
        }else{
            return new Observable as Observable<StudentsDto>;
        }
    }),
    mergeMap((response: StudentsDto) => {
        return response.students.map(student => this.getAddress(student.id))
    }),
    mergeAll(),
);

const subscription = connection.subscribe({
    next(response: AddressDto) {
        // Perform/save operation on Address object
    },
    error(e) {
        console.log(e)
    },
    complete() {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    },
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.